# Issue with Enforce Basic Authentication in Weblogic 12.1.3 Cluser (Windows only)

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

`Enforce Basic Authentication` is not working for a Weblogic Cluster (Windows only)

The below config does not work as expected in Windows for a cluster but does work in Admin Server and CentOS.

```
<enforce–valid–basic–auth–credentials>false</enforce–valid–basic–auth–credentials>
```

Can someone help me to resolve this in Windows + Weblogic 12.1.3 Cluster

Comment: please, improve formatting of your codeblock!

Comment: @naXa - Please suggest an edit to the question next time

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing - sorry, edits must be at least 6 characters.